# Booting from CD-ROM image with HP server in UEFI mode

Tags: centos7, hp, boot, uefi, hpe

I have a ProLiant BL460c Gen9 server, on which I want to install my OS with UEFI mode.
After I changed the boot mode to UEFI and disabled secure-boot and tried to boot my Centos7 Image from CD-ROM this is what I get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qtDn.png

Right after this screen, it will load the previous Centos Image that was booted with legacy.
According to https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/UEFI, there is support for Centos7 images.
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the logic of enabling UEFI and disabling secure-boot ? Do you want to boot from a larger than 2TB drive/partition ?

Comment: Exactly how did you try to boot the installation media? Take a screenshot of that.

Comment: Eventually, it worked for me. Strangely it didn't work when attaching through URL CD-ROM/DVD iso but only when attaching a local file to Virtual media.